# environment and newcommands

Tags: lists, environments

I am writing a summary of my methods in c++ where the outputstyle is always the same like that:

TestFunc (Title as subsection)

Method Boolean TestFunc(Integer MyPar) *(this should be in a Lstlisting environment)*

Description of the Method *(as Text)*

Parameters: *(List of Parameters using itemize  like that:)*

- MyPar: *followed Description of the parameter*

Return values: *(List of Return Values like that):*

- True: *Description1*
- False *Description2*

Since I have lots more to go i was thinking about harmonizing it, using my own
commands and environments.
I thought about something like that:

```
 \newenvironment{Method}{
 \begin{lstlisting}
 Method Boolean TestFunc(Integer MyPar) \end{lstlisting}
 Parameters:
 \begin{itemize}
 \par{Integer}{MyPar}{Description}
 }

 {
 \end{itemize}

 }
```

while \par should be sth like that:
    \newcommand{\par}[3]{\item #2: #3}

How can i combine all this? so it would also be possible to include the par-defined stuff in the lstlisting like:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
 Method Boolean TestFunc(#1 #2) 
\end{lstlisting}
```

And furthermore: Sometimes the methods have no input arguments, sometimes they have three, so I sort of need numbered parameters. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: You can do that but don't call the command `\par` bad things will happen if you do that (it is the tex primitive to typeset a paragraph)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion, fancied up a little with colors and formatting.

It doesn't use the `listings` package, but that's not really necessary here, because you already know pretty well how your output is supposed to be formatted. Additionally, using `listings` would make things complicated because you can't easily pass verbatim arguments through commands/environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\newenvironment{method}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength\parindent{0pt}
  \newcommand\typesetparam[3]{\item[\texttt{\color{blue}##2}] \texttt{##1}: ##3}
  \begingroup\tt
    Method \textcolor{blue}{#2} #1(#3)
    \endgroup\par
  Parameters:
  \begin{description}
}{
  \end{description}
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{method}{TestFunc}{Boolean}{Integer MyPar}
  \typesetparam{MyPar}{Integer}{Description}
\end{method}

\end{document}
```